# What does Shiva purana says about Shiva wear tiger skin and hold a trishul with damru?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, symbolism

[[image: Image of Shiva with tiger skin and trishul]]

According to Shiv puran when did Lord Shiva start to wear tiger skin and hold a trishul with damru? Does it describes any story about it. I have heard that Shiva had killed a tiger and wrapped the skin on his waist. Is it true as per Shiva purana? & how Shiva started to hold trishul with damru?